# react-google-maps polyline with markers is not updating the map when its dataset coming from props is changed

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I am using `react-google-maps` library for showing `polylines` and `markers` on map, and for that I have used this example with the dataset coming from `props` (not hardcoded) and it work fine.

Now what I am trying to achieve is to update the maps when the dataset coming from props is changed, I have logged and checked the data and its changed on every action but the map is not updating itself.

```
import React from "react";
import { compose, withProps } from "recompose";
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  Polyline
} from "react-google-maps";

const MyMapComponent = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL:
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props => (
  <GoogleMap defaultZoom={7} defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.897, lng: 151.144 }}>    /* All these coordinates are coming from props */
    <Polyline 
      options={{
        strokeColor: "red",
        strokeOpacity: 0.75,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        icons: [
            {
                // icon: lineSymbol,
                offset: "0",
                repeat: "20px"
            }
        ]}} 
      path={[{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }, { lat: -35.397, lng: 151.644 }]}   /* All these coordinates are coming from props */
    />
    <Polyline 
      options={{
        strokeColor: "blue",
        strokeOpacity: 0.75,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        icons: [
            {
                // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-custom
                icon: {
                  path: "M -2,0 0,-2 2,0 0,2 z",
                  strokeColor: "blue",
                  fillColor: "blue",
                  fillOpacity: 1,
                },
                offset: "0",
                repeat: "20px"
            }
        ]}} 
      path={[{ lat: -34.397, lng: 155.644 }, { lat: -35.397, lng: 151.644 }]}
    />

    <Marker position={{ lat: -35.397, lng: 151.644 }} onClick={props.onMarkerClick} />  /* All these coordinates are coming from props */
    <Marker 
      position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 155.644 }} onClick={props.onMarkerClick}   /* All these coordinates are coming from props */
      icon={{
        url: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
      }}
    />
    <Marker 
      position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}     /* All these coordinates are coming from props */
      onClick={props.onMarkerClick}
      title="click on it!!"
      label="A"
    />
  </GoogleMap>
));

function Map() {

  const handleMarkerClick = () => {
    alert('Marker Clicked');
  }

  return (
    <MyMapComponent onMarkerClick={handleMarkerClick} />
  )
}

export default Map;
```

Someone please guide me in this, how I can update map with the changed data coming from props periodically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) of your code? You can use [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/).

Comment: just for the sake of avoiding errors, keep in mind that Marker component is for class components, (React 16) and MarkerF for functional (React 18+)

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling the props? I can make it work properly on my end. What I did is, put all the path and coordinates variable and value inside your returned  `<MyMapComponent/>` in the `Map function` then call it inside the `const  <MyMapComponent/>` as `props.variablename`. Everytime I change the value inside the variable in the `Map function`, the changes also reflects on the map. Here is a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-simple-map-nmu8wz?file=Map.js) and code snippet below:

```
import React from "react";
import { compose, withProps } from "recompose";
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  Polyline
} from "react-google-maps";

const MyMapComponent = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL:
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props => (
  <GoogleMap defaultZoom={props.zoom} defaultCenter={props.center}>
    {" "}
    /* All these coordinates are coming from props */
    <Polyline
      options={{
        strokeColor: "red",
        strokeOpacity: 0.75,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        icons: [
          {
            // icon: lineSymbol,
            offset: "0",
            repeat: "20px"
          }
        ]
      }}
      path={props.polyline1} /* All these coordinates are coming from props */
    />
    <Polyline
      options={{
        strokeColor: "blue",
        strokeOpacity: 0.75,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        icons: [
          {
            // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-custom
            icon: {
              path: "M -2,0 0,-2 2,0 0,2 z",
              strokeColor: "blue",
              fillColor: "blue",
              fillOpacity: 1
            },
            offset: "0",
            repeat: "20px"
          }
        ]
      }}
      path={props.polyline2}
    />
    <Marker
      position={props.marker1}
      onClick={props.onMarkerClick}
    />{" "}
    /* All these coordinates are coming from props */
    <Marker
      position={props.marker2}
      onClick={
        props.onMarkerClick
      } /* All these coordinates are coming from props */
      icon={{
        url:
          "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png"
      }}
    />
    <Marker
      position={props.marker3} /* All these coordinates are coming from props */
      onClick={props.onMarkerClick}
      title="click on it!!"
      label="A"
    />
  </GoogleMap>
));

function Map() {
  const handleMarkerClick = () => {
    alert("Marker Clicked");
  };

  return (
    <MyMapComponent
      onMarkerClick={handleMarkerClick}
      zoom={8}
      center={{ lat: -34.897, lng: 151.144 }}
      polyline1={[{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }, { lat: -35.397, lng: 151.644 }]}
      polyline2={[{ lat: -34.397, lng: 155.644 }, { lat: -35.397, lng: 151.644 }]}
      marker1={{ lat: -35.397, lng: 151.644 }}
      marker2={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 155.644 }}
      marker3={{lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}}
    />
  );
}

export default Map;
```